# Javascript website header - hide on scroll down function "Uncaught TypeError: header is null" error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a show/hide header on scroll effect.

I receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: header is null" in the console when scrolling on the page.

I've already tried adding the js script src at the bottom of the body, but still get the same error

I'm unsure of what the issue is, hope someone could help shed some light on what might be going on D:

Hope the documentation is helpful.

```
window.onload = (function(){

  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var w   = window;

  /*
  define four variables: curScroll, prevScroll, curDirection, prevDirection
  */

  var curScroll;
  var prevScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
  var curDirection = 0;
  var prevDirection = 0;

  /*
  how it works:
  -------------
  create a scroll event listener
  create function to check scroll position on each scroll event,
  compare curScroll and prevScroll values to find the scroll direction
  scroll up - 1, scroll down - 2, initial - 0
  then set the direction value to curDirection
  compare curDirection and prevDirection
  if it is different, call a function to show or hide the header
  example:
  step 1: user scrolls down: curDirection 2, prevDirection 0 > hide header
  step 2: user scrolls down again: curDirection 2, prevDirection 2 > already hidden, do nothing
  step 3: user scrolls up: curDirection 1, prevDirection 2 > show header
  */

  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  var toggled;
  var threshold = 200;

  var checkScroll = function() {
      curScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
      if(curScroll > prevScroll) {
          // scrolled down
          curDirection = 2;
      }
      else {
          //scrolled up
          curDirection = 1;
      }

      if(curDirection !== prevDirection) {
          toggled = toggleHeader();
      }

      prevScroll = curScroll;
      if(toggled) {
          prevDirection = curDirection;
      }
  };

  var toggleHeader = function() { 
      toggled = true;
      if(curDirection === 2 && curScroll > threshold) {
          header.classList.add("hide");
      }
      else if (curDirection === 1) {
          header.classList.remove("hide");
      }
      else {
          toggled = false;
      }
      return toggled;
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);

})();
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header" class="header">
        <nav class="navigation-bar">
            <div class="menu-grid-container">
                <div class="menu-popup">
                    <ul class="menu-popup-items">
                        <li>SOME BRAND TEXT</li>
                        <li>SOME BRAND TEXT</li>
                        <li>SOME BRAND TEXT</li>
                        <li>SOME BRAND TEXT</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-grid-top">
                    <div class="menu-grid-top-container">
                        <a href="#" class="header-logo">
                            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1097/6560/files/165px_trans_white_logo.png?v=1616495772" alt="" style="width:165px;height:83px;">
                        </a>
                        <div class="search_wrap search_wrap_4">
                            <div class="search_box">
                                <div class="btn btn_common">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="search..." style="border:none">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="header-account-button">
                                <span>
                                    <svg class="svg-account" viewBox="0 0 14 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M2.917 5.4c0-2.322 1.828-4.2 4.083-4.2s4.083 1.878 4.083 4.2c0 2.316-1.828 4.2-4.083 4.2S2.917 7.716 2.917 5.4zm6.651 4.704A5.415 5.415 0 0 0 12.25 5.4C12.25 2.418 9.9 0 7 0S1.75 2.418 1.75 5.4a5.415 5.415 0 0 0 2.682 4.704C1.838 11.16 0 13.758 0 16.8V18h1.167v-1.2c0-3.318 2.611-6 5.833-6 3.221 0 5.833 2.682 5.833 6V18H14v-1.2c0-3.042-1.838-5.64-4.432-6.696z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                        </path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                                
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="header-cart-button">
                                <span>
                                    <svg class="svg-basket" viewBox="0 0 23 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                        <defs><path id="a" d="M0 0h23.037v17.063H0z"></path></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                        <mask id="b" fill="#fff;"><use xlink:href="#a"></use></mask>
                                        <path d="M20.91 8.78h-4.64V6h5.572l-.932 2.78zm-1.268 3.78H16.27V9.78h4.305l-.933 2.78zm-1.174 3.503H16.27V13.56h3.037l-.84 2.504zm-10.702 0h7.504V13.56H7.766v2.504zM3.729 13.56h3.037v2.504H4.569l-.84-2.504zm3.037-3.78v2.78H3.394l-.932-2.78h4.304zm0-3.779v2.78h-4.64L1.196 6h5.57zm1 6.56h7.504V9.78H7.766v2.78zm0-3.78h7.504V6H7.766v2.78zm0-6.863c0-.506.412-.917.917-.917h5.67c.506 0 .917.411.917.917V5H7.766V1.917zm15.177 3.291A.5.5 0 0 0 22.537 5H16.27V1.917A1.92 1.92 0 0 0 14.353 0h-5.67a1.92 1.92 0 0 0-1.917 1.917V5H.5a.498.498 0 0 0-.474.659l3.71 11.063a.501.501 0 0 0 .474.341H18.827a.501.501 0 0 0 .474-.34l3.71-11.064a.5.5 0 0 0-.068-.45z" fill="#FFF"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-grid-bottom">
                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul class="menu-items">
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">MENU ITEM</a>
                            <div class="mega-menu">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <section>
                                            <h2>Section 1</h2>
                                            <ul class="mega-links">
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <section>
                                            <h2>Section 2</h2>
                                            <ul class="mega-links">
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <section>
                                            <h2>Section 3</h2>
                                            <ul class="mega-links">
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></a>Menu Item</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-bottom">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                        <a href="#" class="mega-menu-image">
                                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/100?grayscale" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="mega-menu-image">
                                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/100?grayscale" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="mega-menu-image">
                                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/100?grayscale" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu_bg"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-2">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-3">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-4">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-5">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-6">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-7">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="section">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque molestiae sit voluptate dicta iusto, a eligendi deserunt dolor quas consectetur nisi culpa fugiat omnis ut illum quod minima voluptas tenetur?</h1>
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, reprehenderit veniam? Cupiditate possimus qui impedit aut dolorem laboriosam sed labore, quisquam, unde quam accusantium esse at perspiciatis rem hic. Cumque.</h2>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS hide style to be applied:

```
#header .hide {
    padding-top: -100px;
  }
```

Comment: You have `<header id="site-header" class="header">` but you're using `var header = document.getElementById("header");`. That won't work. You can use 1. `document.getElementById('site-header')` or 2. `document.querySelector('header')` or 3. `document.querySelector('#site-header')` or 4. `document.querySelector('.header')` or 5. `document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0]` or 6. `document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0]`

Comment: Also note that you're supposed to use `window.onload = function () {...}` or better `window.addEventListener('load', function () {...})`; what you have instead is an IIFE, meaning the code runs immediately, not after the window.onload event has triggered. So fixing just the `var header` assignment won't work unless you also move the function below the <header> element, in which case you can remove the window.onload assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `document.getElementById("header");` but there is no element with the `id="header"` attribute. I guess what you need is `document.getElementById("site-header");`